# jQuery Sliding Form Expanding Outside of Parent Element's "Wrapper"

Tags: javascript, jquery, styling, jquery-effects

I'm trying to build a basic contact form using jQuery. The markup is essentially a `<section>` containing a second-level heading (`<h2>`) and a `<div>` containing labels for a sibling `<form`>. My desired effect is to have the label container and the form appear by sliding down when the second-level heading is clicked. This is currently working, but the two containers expand outside of their parent element. To see what I mean by this, you can view a page I constructed that is identical in terms of the section in question to the page I am actually building [here](http://taylorcopeland.com/issues/sliding-form.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the CSS to:

```
#contact {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Wow. It's been a while... I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: and you dont need the `height:auto`